# migrating cassandra from 1.1.2 to 1.2.6

Tags: cassandra

My current cassandra version is 1.1.2, it is implemented with a single node cluster, i would like to upgrade it 1.2.6 with multiple nodes in the ring. is it a proper way to migrate it directly to 1.2.6 or i should follow version by version migration.

I found the upgrading steps from this link
[http://fossies.org/linux/misc/apache-cassandra-1.2.6-bin.tar.gz:a/apache-cassandra-1.2.6/NEWS.txt](http://fossies.org/linux/misc/apache-cassandra-1.2.6-bin.tar.gz%3aa/apache-cassandra-1.2.6/NEWS.txt).

There are 9 other releases available between this two versions.

Answer (score 2):

I migrate a two cluster nodes from 1.1.6 to 1.2.6 without problems and without doing version by version. Anyway, you should take a closer look into:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/index.html?pagename=docs&version=1.2&file=index#upgrade/upgradeC_c.html#concept_ds_smb_nyr_ck

Because there are a lot of new features from version 1.2 like the partioners maybe you need to change some configurations for your cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You may directly hop on to C1.2.6.

We migrated our 4-node cluster from C1.0.9 to C1.2.8 recently without any issues.  This was a rolling upgrade i.e. upgrade one node at a time and after each upgrade of a node, allow the cluster to stabilize (depends upon the traffic during upgrade)

These are the steps that we followed:

Perform below on each node,

1. Run Disablegossip and disablethrift, such that this node is seen as DOWN by other nodes.
2. flush/drain the memtables, run compaction to merge SSTables
3. take snapshot and enable incremental backups
4. This stops all the other nodes/clients from writing to this node and since memtables are flushed to disk, startup times are fast as it need not walk-through commit logs.
5. stop Cassandra (though this node is down, cluster is available for write/read, so zero downtime)
6. upgrade sstables to new storage format using sstableupgrade
7. install/untar Cassandra 1.2.8 on the new locations
8. move upgraded sstables to appropriate location
9. merge Cassandra.yaml from previous version and current version by a manual diff (need to detail out difference)
10. start Cassandra
11. watch the startup messages to ensure the node comes up without difficulty and is shown in the ring with mixed 1.0.x/1.2.x